# How to set the texture of a spatial material on a mesh instance in gd script in godot

Tags: textures, mesh, godot

I have a mesh instance and I want to have a function that takes in a file path of a png file and adds it to spatial material and then adds the material to the mesh instance. I tried using the following:

```
var mat = SpatialMaterial.new() 
var tex = Texture.new() 
tex.resource_path = "res://icon.png" 
mat.albedo_texture = tex 
mesh.material_override = mat
```

but it returned this error on line 3:
`Invalid set index 'resource_path' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'String'.`

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out.  I just needed to use the load function.  The following code works:

```
var mat = SpatialMaterial.new() 
var tex = load("res://icon.png")
mat.albedo_texture = tex 
mesh.material_override = mat
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.